# Money sent to wallet was removed in unexpected second transaction 30 minutes later

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, client

I got sent bitcoins to my cake address then the coins went into the account as unconfirmed for about half an hour then they were sent to another address, and the confirmations have finished and i dont have any coins in my account they are sitting in this other account which is similiar address to the one i sent to , so its a cake address, im wondering if i hit refresh bitcoin addy it will go to this new address that was created ? am i on the right track ?
cf5471592253c04cf12a6aba559a7aec531df42cee4a87f85968ce4187dddc16

anyhelp would be great

Comment: What is a 'cake address'? It isn't clear to me what your question is, or what you're trying to do.

Comment: cake the android app, populated a bitcoin address which i used to send to, but it went there then got sent on to another address simliar to the first one but i dont know how to access it, im wondering if i press refresh new bitcoin addy in the cake app it will be the new address it was sent to

Comment: Does the wallet currently show a balance? It is strange behaviour to have the coins forwarded to another address. Are you sure it is a legitimate wallet? I haven’t heard of cake wallet before.

Comment: How did you determine "the coins were sent to another address"? Do you mean that the initial transaction got replaced by another transaction? Which address were you trying to get paid to? Is cf547159… the transaction that paid you or the transaction that paid the other address that it went to eventually?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your money was stolen. Either the app is fake or broken or someone had access to your wallet at sometime (maybe they helped you set it up).

A blockchain explorer shows (most recent at top)

```
Transactions involving address
```

```
Hash: c423c3d9d4e72b16cbfb3a3c1a47c578a56f51bf00be4ecb07c588d957f7cf46

2021-05-21 01:01  55 confirmations  Privacy score: 55

Senders
  0.05796927 BTC    bc1qs69asfc0c0we5ynauzsfjtm7hwp6du6vs40srf

Recipients
   bc1q8tdu705hjqxlzar2mretdrcesuezkzphad2amc  0.05784046 BTC Unspent
```

```
Hash: cf5471592253c04cf12a6aba559a7aec531df42cee4a87f85968ce4187dddc16

2021-05-21 01:01 55 confirmations  Privacy score: 49

Senders
  0.01025588 BTC        35KKBAGr5ch6dwMYzrxW1oVdCvMHHoCuKn
  0.04729191 BTC        3QEUGgo3LsLFFqAV38q5bCxP3nH1phbyPi
  0.00069646 BTC        3JervgE4EoMhjbAYH11pQnsxTDQBeK7FKu

Recipients  
  bc1qs69asfc0c0we5ynauzsfjtm7hwp6du6vs40srf
```

So money was sent in and a second transaction immediately removed it.

Just because both addresses start bc1 doesn't mean they are both Cakewallet addresses. Thats not how addresses work. Apart from the `bc1` or `3` prefix, they are visually random.