# I sent bitcoins from one wallet to another. Next day, the receiving wallet shows balance 0

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, receiving

I have sent some bitcoins from bitcoin.com to the crypto app wallet, yesterday. But, the app still shows 0 bitcoin balance. I checked the receiving address on the block explorer and it showed that the transitions were successful. Today, I checked again. It strangely shows that the bitcoins send to an unknown address. So, could anyone please help to understand what's going on? Can I get my bitcoins back?

[image]

As you can see, 18deMYeiAe45x3fqbzhN15vafPNuSRYaCM was the sending address and 35qerZ6FLCshwCLwqv8JzgoLr9YDfCMquh was the receiving message. But there is another transaction which I have no idea about. Why does my bitcoin fund sent to an unknown address?

Just to clarify, "the crypto app" isn't crypto.com. It's thecrypto.app

Comment: This seems similar to [Money sent to wallet was removed in unexpected second transaction 30 minutes later](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/106476/13866)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Money sent to wallet was removed in unexpected second transaction 30 minutes later](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106476/money-sent-to-wallet-was-removed-in-unexpected-second-transaction-30-minutes-lat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "crypto app wallet" is the **[crypto.com app](https://crypto.com/app)**, that appears to be a **"custodial account"**, not a normal [non-custodial wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866). In that case it might be just crypto.com consolidating funds. You should *contact their customer support* about your account balance.

If the "crypto app wallet" is the **[crypto.com wallet](https://crypto.com/defi-wallet)**, that appears to be a **non-custodial wallet**. This is a more normal kind of wallet. In that case it could be  your money was stolen. You should perhaps *review security* of computer, wallet, backups and private-keys or recovery phrases.

If the "crypto app wallet" is the **[thecrypto.app app](https://thecrypto.app/)**, that is a **custodial account**  not a normal [non-custodial wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81240/13866). In that case it might be just thecrypto.app consolidating funds. You should *contact their customer support* about your account balance.

---

https://help.thecrypto.app/?article=1 says

> The Crypto App wallet is a hosted wallet. That means we host the private keys

Remember, **"Not your keys, not your Bitcoin"**.

https://help.thecrypto.app/?article=12 says

> Contacting wallet support
> Please contact our wallet partner using this contact form. Wallet functionality in The Crypto App is provided by Crypterium. The Crypto App support team does not have access and insights into your account.

To me this seems a long way away from the original intent of Satoshi Nakamoto when he created Bitcoin as a way of removing any need to rely on trusted third parties.

Answer (score 0):

They consolidated your funds with other clients inputs. If this is legit or a scam you can find out if you try to withdraw your funds again.
Anothe chance usually is tracing the bitcoin but in your case it maes no sense because the potential lst value is too low.